# Angular 5: Service to share data between Components (across Modules)?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-material2, angular-services, angular-module

I have this simple Service which is a `provider` in two Modules:

```typescript
@Injectable()
export class PlatformPickerService {
  platforms: string[] = [
    'macOS', 'Linux', 'Windows'
  ];
  public platform: string;

  constructor() {
    this.platform = this.platforms[1];
  }

  public getPlatform(): string {
    const platform = localStorage.getItem('platform');
    return platform == null ? this.platform : platform;
  }

  public setPlatform(platform: string) {
    this.platform = platform;
    localStorage.setItem('platform', platform);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, nowhere I use it acquired the chosen value. Using it outside its Module gives only the default value, using it inside its Module gives no value.

Full test-case: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aru94g-2djexv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working: https://angular-aru94g-w6qy21.stackblitz.io ([edit](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aru94g-w6qy21))

Major changes were:

#### Component

```typescript
updateService(event: any) {
    if (event.value != null) this.platformPickerService.setPlatform(event.value);
}
```

```all
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Platform" shouldLabelFloat="false"
              [(ngModel)]="platformSelectd"
              (selectionChange)=updateService($event)>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let platform of platformPickerService.platforms"
                [value]=platform>
      {{ platform }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

### Module

- Only have `PlatformPickerService` in one Module (app.module)

---

Now it's time to try rewriting the setters/getters once more and see if that'll work (`setPlatform` to `set platform`) =3

Comment: Does changing default value in Service take effect in dropdown box?

Comment: Yes, it does indeed.

Comment: Is it ? In ur demo shows MacOS as default but in PlatformPickerService default value set to platforms[1] which is "Linux".

Answer (score 1):

Services are singletons within the scope of an injector. Define the PlatformPickerService as provider in app module or root module and make it as singleton service. This will be application scoped singleton service.

Ok, Issue with your PlatformPickerComponent. You have to send the selected value to updateService.

- Property Binding -[] => Component to Template  -- one way binding,
  Changing value doesn't update the property in component

  > [value]="platformSelected"
- Event Binding - () => Template to component

  > (change)="updateService($event.value)"
- PlatformPickerService moved to app module for this example and set as application scoped provider.

Please check the [sample app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aru94g-kn2ynf) and [demo](https://angular-aru94g-kn2ynf.stackblitz.io).

Default platform value set in PlatformPickerService whenever change this it is reflected in drop down box as selected value.

```
  constructor() {
    this.platform = this.platforms[4];
  }
```

Comment: I have it in app.module. I tried taking it out of platform-picker.module XOR taking it out of app.module; bug remains :(

Comment: Comment to your edit: I tried putting `updateService` into the `{{` template; same error

Comment: @AT Updated you app with some minor modification. hth.

Comment: Thanks @nayakam; that was almost right, edited it a little: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aru94g-w6qy21 <- that works perfectly | maybe add this link to your answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: Included  your answer. Glad that it worked for you. (Y)

Comment: Ah damn, just been debugging it for the last 15 minutes. Getting the default value from `localStorage` and applying that everywhere isn't working (how do I set the default in `mat-select`?). Tried with the `[value]` line, does that need to be 2 way?

Comment: Ended up spending another 45 minutes on it, so ended up adding my own answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47869704

Comment: @AT I just updated my answer to clarify the changes and default value being set to drop down when you set it service.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161491/discussion-between-nayakam-and-a-t).

Answer (score 0):

You've missed two-way binding in the `PlatformPickerComponent`
Add import of `FormsModule` into the `PlatformPickerModule` and change the `PlatformPickerComponent` as below:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Platform" shouldLabelFloat="false" [(ngModel)]="platform">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let platform of platformPickerService.platforms"
                [value]="platform">
      {{ platform }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>



import {AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

import {PlatformPickerService} from './platform-picker.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'platform-picker',
  templateUrl: './platform-picker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./platform-picker.component.css']
})
export class PlatformPickerComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  private _platform: string;

  constructor(public platformPickerService: PlatformPickerService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._platform = this.platformPickerService.getPlatform();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
  }

   get platform(): string {
    return this._platform;
  }

  set platform(value: string) {
    if (value != null) {
      this.platformPickerService.setPlatform(value);
      this._platform = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I kind of cheated the two way because the `(selected)=updateService()` didn't get called; so it hits the model with `[value]` and thus the fix you found wouldn't work, right? - PS: I had `get platform` and `set platform` in my service, but I took that out after people on Gitter/angular told me to; are they okay to use?

Answer (score 0):

I made couple of changes to your existing code.
If you are using two way binding then you can skip ngModelChange
Otherwise use oneway binding along with ngModelChange as follows.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [ngModel]="selected" (ngModelChange)="updateService($event)"  placeholder="Platform" shouldLabelFloat="false" [(value)]="selected">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let platform of platformPickerService.platforms"
                [value]="platform">
      {{ platform }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

and you updateService function as follows

```
updateService(newPlatform) {
    console.log(newPlatform);
    if (newPlatform != null) {
      this.selected = newPlatform;
      this.platformPickerService.setPlatform(this.selected);
    }
  }
```

you can check the code here
[https://angular-aru94g-agtn1m.stackblitz.io](https://angular-aru94g-bjgeaf.stackblitz.io/)

Comment: Thanks, but that demo doesn't work. The select doesn't default and changing the drop down value doesn't change it elsewhere (I.e.: other Component).

Comment: sorry by mistake i provided u the link which was not forked. But the above code is correct. and u have pasted the same answer.